# Unable to call stored procedure on Azure Synapse Analytics database

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, mulesoft, mule4

I am trying to call a stored procedure on Azure Synapse Analytics. I am only able to use the `exec` command to execute the stored procedure in Azure Data Studio to retrieve the results.

```
EXEC [DBSCHEMA].[SPNAME] param1,param2...
```

If am trying to call the stored procedure via the stored procedure palette in the Database Connector module in Mule 4.

I am getting this error:

> Cursor Support is not an implemented feature for SQL Server Parallel DataWareHousing TDS endpoint

I am using JDBC Driver version 11.1.0.jre8

I have tried various options like Execute Script in Database Connector Module, which doesn't return the result set, looks like it's only updating/committing records only. I am getting the result as [-2].

*I know this is Azure Synapse Analytics warehouse works a little differently than the actual database. Can anyone else provide any other better alternatives here than just calling
the exec command in SQL to execute the stored procedure?*

Comment: It's a **stored** procedure - as in a procedure **stored** inside your database engine - it has nothing to do with a "store" ....

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mule, but the problem doesn't seem to be the way you're calling the stored procedure - that's valid syntax.  The stored procedure you're calling must include Cursors, which aren't supported on Synapse.  I think the question you need to ask, is how to re-write a stored procedure not to use Cursors.

Comment: Can you follow the below techcommunity article and see if you can use your SQL statement in the below format


EXEC ('DDL/DML') at yourLinkedServer


https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-synapse-analytics-blog/remotely-run-ddl-and-dml-in-synapse-from-a-sql-managed-instance/ba-p/2157122

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/sql-statement-failed-azure-synapse-cursor-support-not-implemented-feature-sql-server-parallel-datawarehousing-tds-endpoint